# Counting specific items in a column, that contains one or multiple answers for each row

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I asked people the following question:
Which fruit do you like? (multiple choice)

- apple
- pear
- peach
- raspberry
- banana
- blueberry
- none

these answers are stored into the following table:

```
Dataset $Fruit 
    fruit
id  apple, banana
id  apple,peach,raspberry
id  none
id  blueberry
id  apple, blueberry,banana, raspberry, peach
etc.
```

I try to find out how many times people named each piece of fruit

```
Fruit_items <- c(“apple”,”pear”,”peach”,”raspberry”,”banana”,”blueberry”, “none”)

item <- vector()
count <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(fruit_items)){
    print(i)
    item[i] <- fruit_items[i]
    count[i] <- sum(items[i] %in% Dataset$Fruit)
}
df2 <- data.frame(items,count)
```

Which returns the following dataframe:

```
  items        counts
1 apple        1
2 pear         1
3 peach        1
4 raspberry    1
5 banana       1
6 blueberry    1
7 none         1
```

Combined with the following warning message:

> Warning message:
>   Unknown or uninitialised column:`apple`.

Seems like it doesn't count any fruits in the list. Can someone help me out on this one?

I would very much appreciate it :)

Comment: Could you include the output of ```dput(Dataset)```? you can even do ```dput(Dataset$Fruit)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split `fruit` column on comma and count using `table`.

```
table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(df$fruit, ','))))
```

In `tidyverse`, we can use `separate_rows` to get data in different rows and then use `count`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate_rows(fruit, sep = ',') %>% count(fruit)
#Or probably
#df %>% separate_rows(fruit, sep = ',\\s?') %>%  count(fruit)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
 table(unlist(strsplit(df$fruit, ',\\s*')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will also get you the same result:

```
as.data.frame(colSums(sapply(Fruit_items, function(x,y)str_count(y, x), Dataset$Fruit)))
```

Output:

```
#          colSums(sapply(Fruit_items, function(x, y) str_count(y, x), data$Fruit))
#apple                                                                            3
#pear                                                                             0
#peach                                                                            2
#raspberry                                                                        2
#banana                                                                           2
#blueberry                                                                        2
#none                                                                             1
```